# How to Sum Visible Rows Only SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rows, hidden, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to sum only the visible rows only in SSRS and I have read a few forums that say you need to put:

```
=Sum( iif( <The condition of Visibility.Hidden expression>, 0, Fields!A.Value))
```

However I am unsure on how this works, my visibility code is:

```
 =iif(Fields!Sub.Value = "Ins", True, IIF(Fields!Sub.Value = "Ins - Int", True, False))
```

When I add this into the above 1st code i get #ERROR.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `=` before the inner `IIF()`-> `=Sum(IIF(=IIF())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Sum(iif( 
Fields!Sub.Value = "Ins", 
0, 
IIF(Fields!Sub.Value = "Ins - Int", 0, Fields!A.Value)
))
```

Note I am not using the same expression for hiding the rows, I am just using its logic.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for, let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you so much. The only bit I had to change was the 0 to NOTHING then it worked perfectly. thanks again